# Excel filtering and auto filling cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make an excel spreadsheet to track my investments and I'm not sure how to create a function to autofill out my sheets. Currently, I have a raw sheet where I dump all my buys sells, and deposits with dates, company name, how much per stock, and how many I bought/sold (each event is allocated a ID to help pull from the sheet). I also have 3 other sheets to separate my buys and sells and deposits. I'm trying to make it so when I put information into the raw it filters itself into its associated sheet, buys goes into the buy sheet, deposits go into the deposit sheet, and so on and so on. I'm using iferror and vlookup to separate the data and autofill into the appropriate sheet but I've run into an issue where I'm not sure how to filter it based on whether it's a buy/sell or deposit. Could I please get some help?

Comment: What excel version do you have? You can use Power Query or the new array functions

Comment: I have 2016, ive never used Power Query or new array functions do you have any video suggestions?